# Android App crashing on some devices like Samsung when scrolling through recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash

I am currently developing an android app which has images loaded from the app into a recyclerview. The application is working on some devices but I noticed that on my Samsung Galaxy S5, the app keeps crashing when I scroll through the recyclerview . I need help

Comment: When it comes to crashing of an application, one of the most effective ways is to read the error log. Therefore, please share the error log in order to determine the reason for the crash.

Comment: @Nero sorry for the late reply. I am getting the following error in logcat                     `` java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9630732 byte allocation with 3326552 free bytes and 3MB until OOM``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OutOfMemoryError is a common error and often occurs in cases when dealing with bitmaps. This occurs due to lack of memory which can't be allocated. In order to resolve this, please implement the following in your  tag within the manifest file.
 Remember to include this in the activity that's throwing the error so in this case it's the activity with recyclerview.

```
android:hardwareAccerlerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Hopefully you should be able to resolve the issue with these attributes.

Any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found at after searching that , though the images had smaller sizes, the dimensions were large. What I finally did was using imagemagic to resize all the images to 50% their initial sizes and everything works perfectly now.